# What is the best way to filter a list of database records that can only be filtered through javascript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

## Question:

Suppose I have a list of database records in ASP.NET MVC Web Application. What is the best way to filter this list by a criteria that can only be filtered through Javascript?

If my question is not clear, Please see the example below.

## Example:

I have a controller action that returns all or portion of my restaurants in the database and in its view I'm showing all these restaurants:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View(restaurantRepository.GetAll());
}
```

Now each restaurant has a service boundary which is a polygon and i'm storing this polygon in the database through the following model property:

```
public class Restaurant
{
      // Other properties omitted...

      public ICollection<Coordinate> Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

`Coordinates` is basically a collection of Latitude/Longitude objects representing a polygon.

Now i want the functionality that if i give `Index` action a point in the map (Latitude/Longitude), then `Index` action should only return the restaurants which contain this point in their service boundary (polygon).

Now obviously I can't do this filtering in the controller because <s>drawing polygons and checking if a point exists in them are only done through Google Maps API and Javascript.</s>

**Edit:**
Thanks to the suggestion by @amg-argh i searched a bit to see if i can check whether a point is inside a polygon only with C/C# and i found [this](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) post which works. Nevertheless my question remains.

What would be the best way to achieve this filtering through Javascript?

#### My Own Thoughts:

What came to my mind was to

- First return all the restaurants to the view.
- Then in the view I deserialize my model with

  `var model = @Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore }));`
- Then iterate through my model with forEach and extract the restraurants that have that criteria met.

  ```
  model.forEach(function(restaurant){
          if(checkBoundaries(restaurant, latLng))
          {
             // Valid restaurant. Save the id in an array.
          }
          else
          {
             // Invalid restaurant. discard it.
          }
  });
  ```
- Then send the valid restaurants array with an AJAX post request to a controller action that returns the restaurants for the given restaurant Ids.

But these all seem like a lot of work and a bad practice. Any ideas?

Comment: You absolutely could do this in C# a google search of "c# point in polygon latitude longitude" might get you some results. But what are you actually trying to achieve, do you want to display a list of "restaurants that will service you at your current location", or are you trying to populate a database that you will use for some other reason later?

Comment: @amg-argh, Exactly. I want to display a list of "restaurants that will service you at your current location".

Comment: Then there is no need to send back to the server? In your `model.forEach` when `checkBoundaries() === true`, could you not then just add a marker (or take other intended action)? _I assume your Restaurant class has the other required information_

Comment: @amg-argh, But how can i remove/discard the restaurants that are invalid. My view is showing my model (all restaurants) that is returned by the `index` action. Should i make an empty view and create all the html elements that show my list through javascript?

Comment: If you view is "Here are n places that will deliver you stuff", then yes I would send out an _empty_ view and render it with javascript. However I would also make some other changes, 1) return the list of restaurants via a WebApi; 2) Filter the list as best as you can (if you know the biggest service radius is 50km, then there is no way a place 200km away could be valid, and you can get away never sending it to the client). But one thing at a time.

Comment: @amg-argh, Thanks to you, I searched a bit and found [this](http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/) post that implements a method that checks if a point is inside a polygon in C. I tested it and it works. But i still like to know what is the best practice if my filtering can only be done through Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question might actually be suited to another stackexchange site, as it's more about program design than actual implementation. Nevertheless, to achieve this on the Frontend rather than the backend.

1. Load your view via the `Index` method, this view should really only contain stub HTML and basic elements that you need for your view. Think headers, footers, titles etc (and potentially a FrontEnd template)
2. Load your list of restaurants via AJAX, using WebApi. So move `return View(restaurantRepository.GetAll());` into web api and do something like `return Ok(restaurantRespostory.GetAll())`.
3. Iterate through the result, when `if(checkBoundaries(restaurant, latLng))` passes, add an HTML Element / Marker to the map / whatever view you are trying to display to your view, using JavaScript. When it fails, ignore it, do nothing.

That's basically all you want to do, and will save you a postback and a second round trip to the server.

*Though I would suggest a few other changes too*

1. Use a frontend MVVM/MVC framework (angularjs, react, knockout, etc), to render your results via JavaScript. Filter your array and have it bound to the view with something like `myViewVariable.inBoundryRestraunts = model.filter(function(r){ return checkBoundaries(r, latLng);})`. It is much tidier to do it this way, rather than creating a bunch of HTMLElement on the fly.
2. Find someway (that doesn't need to be perfect) to limit the results from the backend still. Although I don't know the specific details of your application I can imagine that an average sized city will have thousands if not tens of thousands of restaurants. Downloading all this data to be processed on the frontend **will** take a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. The angularjs/react/knockout tip was great.